# Объявить переменную в любой точке пространства кода

Tags: ассемблер, fasm

Мне нужно объявить переменную в любой точке кода, например

```
use16               
org 100h
;код
;представим что тут есть код
;код
;отсюда переменная не доступна
text db 'C' ; и вот захотелось мне здесь объявить переменную
;отсюда переменная доступна
;а дальше 
;код
;представим что тут есть код
;код
```

Как это сделать корректно и без ошибок? неужели придется `jmp $+2`?

Comment: А что, fasm не видит переменных, которые выделены позже, чем используются ? мне казалось ассемблеры все переменные всегда видят

Comment: я знаю что видит и до объявления. Но просто стало интересно как из откуда нибудь объявить переменную.

Comment: Заметьте, я не сказал "объявить", я сказал "выделить". переменные в ассемблере обычно не объявляются, а выделяется память под них и выделяется именно там, где написана. Правда если у вас не com файл, а exe вы по идее можете в любом месте сказать, что тут сегмент данных, объявить переменную и опять начать сегмент кода. при этом они будут в совершенно разных местах в памяти и jmp не понадобятся. ну есть еще некие локальные переменные, но это я не в курсе https://stackoverflow.com/a/27204390/5669174

Answer (score 1):

Для процессора код и данные выглядят одинаково. Если вы на пути выполнения кода вставили какие-то данные, то процессор попытается их выполнить как код. Поэтому для данных внутри исполняемого кода придется делать `jmp` через данные.

На вашем примере:

```
use16               
org 100h
;код
;представим что тут есть код
;код

jmp next
text db 'C' ; и вот захотелось мне здесь объявить переменную
next:

;а дальше 
;код
;представим что тут есть код
;код
```

Переменная (метка) `text` будет доступна и выше и ниже по коду.

Такой способ объявления переменных я бы не рекомендовал к использованию:

- если область памяти доступна для записи, то можно легко затереть код, например если по адресу `text` попытаться записать больше одного байта, например так:

  ```
  mov word [text], 'C'
  ```
- если область памяти недоступна для записи (например, если это область кода с правами только на чтение и исполнение под Windows или *nix), то при попытке записи получим исключение
- ну и в целом, лучше когда данные объявлены отдельно от кода - либо в отдельной глобальной области, либо как локальные переменные в стеке.